# How to bring iphone app from background to foreground without user interaction when push notification comes in objective c?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification

Please suggest me objective c code for bringing the app from background to foreground without any user interaction when push notification comes.

Comment: What makes you think this is even possible?

Comment: NOT possible, you cannot do anything without user interaction..

Comment: @Dilip: You can show notifications when your app is not in foreground. But you can't launch your app without any user interaction

Comment: @MidhunMP you are right.

Comment: i think this man asking something, what he really don't know.
i don't know whey people downvoting his question.
Guys please correct me if i am wrong.can some ask something what he/ she really don't know

Comment: So i m gonna upvote his question.

Comment: Even if you could do that, don't do that! Users HATE when something pops in the screen without their permission!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible as Notification come and your app started automatically even without user interaction.

As Push Notification comes it Handles by OS.

If a notification for an application arrives when that application is not running, the device alerts the user that the application has data waiting for it.

Then It means user have to interact with the Device.

From The Apple Doc.

`When the operating system delivers  push notification (iOS or OS X) and the target application is not running in the foreground, it presents the notification (alert, icon badge number, sound). If there is a notification alert and the user taps or clicks the action button (or moves the action slider), the application launches and calls a method to pass in the local-notification object or remote-notification payload. If the application is running in the foreground when the notification is delivered, the application delegate receives a local or push notification.`

That's All.

I hope it clears to you.

Comment: then how is it possible in whatsapp when someone call us ?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its possible. Once push notification came, the os itself handles and show notification if it is enabled for your app. Then from the notification, if you are going to app, then didReceiveRemotenotification callback will be fired.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but it would require a jailbroken iPhone and hook the push notification receiver to launch your app when the notification is received.

If you aim for App Store you can't.