# Local/Push-Notification and launch app

Tags: iphone, ios7, push-notification, xcode5, uilocalnotification

I have faced problem in below scenario.

1) App is in background.

2) Push notification.

3) Launch app as per as push notification's text.(For the launch app i have use custom URL scheme)

Eq.I have register push notification in **A.ipa** and wants launch **B.ipa** via pushnotification.

Is it possible to launch application from **Local/Push-Notification(iOS7)**?

or

Is there any other way to communicate with background app and launch other app?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use URLSchemes to launch another App(**B**) from your App(**A**). But **B** App should be registered with URL Schemes.

You can search for **URL Schemes** and go through the tutorials available.

Comment: Yes,B is register with  URL Schemes.It is successfully launch while **A.ipa** is in foreground.But I want to know ,Is Push notification able to lunch **B.ipa** while **A.ipa** in foreground mode?.

Comment: Does below API work while my application in background ?(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"HelloTest://aaTest.com.HelloTest"]];
        // }
}

Comment: I never tried that,but i think this link has some info regarding your question: http://nshipster.com/launch-options/

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is possible to launch application from Local/Push-Notification. Actually, this is the default behavior.

Prior to **iOS7**, notifications were all "verbose", meaning that the user is presented an alert view which allows him to launch the app if he wants, or to dismiss the notification, leaving the application unaware. **iOS7** has introduced silent push notifications, which launch the application without user interaction.

Comment: Can i achieve the same things when Socket communication established and app is in background?

Comment: I have try with local Notification,It can't able to launch new B.ipa from background.Are sure push notification launch B.ipa while it is background.

Comment: Through native notifications, an application can maybe launch another application through an URL whose protocol specifically targets the second application. Regarding your own sockets: you understand that exist in your own application, and die when your application dies: they won't receive any data when your app is not launched.

Comment: I strongly recommend you read http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html - this is a top-notch article about multi-tasking in iOS. You'll learn strictly about system-provided APIs, and for a reason: iOS will let you manage your own lifetime *exclusively* through those APIs.

Comment: I go through your suggested link and get idea about the multitasking.

Comment: still i am confuse about,Is push notification is able to launch b.ipa in background mode?

Comment: '(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"HelloTest://aaTest.com.HelloTest"]];
        // }
}'

Comment: Refer this link,which says it is not possible to launch the application without user interaction ,[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909856/how-to-bring-iphone-app-from-background-to-foreground-without-user-interaction-w

Comment: Read again, and thoroughly this time, the objc.io article linked above. Isn't it much more engaging than quick stackoverflow answers? Come on, you have to be able to recognize talent when you see it. So go read it again. You'll learn about silent push notifications, which can launch apps without user interaction. It is unknown to me, however, if they are able to launch another app through [UIApplication openURL:].